# ios comparing memcache and core data

Tags: php, mysql, ios, core-data, memcached

Currently in order to limit the number of mysql requests, each user has a folder with multiple empty files corresponding to updates made in the database.  The last accessed date of a file is compared to a date stored in core data.  Only if the last accessed date is after the date in core data does the db get queried.

For example, if userA sends a friend request to userB, this is written to the db and the file /userB/friend is touched to update the date last assessed to the current date.  Now when userB gets to a script that queries the db for his friend requests, it first checks if the last accessed date of /userB/friend is after the date in core data and only runs it if this is the case.  The new last accessed date along with the data from the query are then stored in core data.

My question is, are there any foreseeable issues with this method I am currently using and is it any better or worse then using memcached to avoid querying the same data over and over again?

I also realize the title of this post is a little mislabeled but I don't know if a name for the method I am using exists.

Comment: From your question it is not clear what the relationship is between mysql and core data. Are you using a MySQL store with Core Data? That is an unusual setup, but certainly feasible in some situations.

Comment: mysql is holding all the data.  When a db request is made it stores the results in core data locally so that the application doesn't have to use network and db resources to get this same information over and over again.

Comment: Very confusing. State clearly which db you mean...

Comment: @Landon It's been a couple of months since you posted this solution, but it seems like you're trying to implement cache invalidation using datestamps. You should profile a solution using memcached vs. your solution using file datestamps. I have a feeling that memcached will be faster, because it doesn't have to touch the server filesystem as much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use date stamps of files instead of database request. I cannot imagine that this is a feasible substitution. To find out for sure you could run some tests, e.g. by doing 100.000 requests with both methods and comparing the performance.

I recommend to store the date information in the database instead. These per user requests should take only a trivial amount of time. If this is not the case you most likely have other more serious problems that impact performance.

Comment: I am not using date stamps of files in lieu of making a database request.  I am using the date stamp to decide whether or not information pertaining to that particular user has been updated in the database and if it has then it does the database request.  If the information hasn't been updated since the last time it checked the database then it does nothing and uses only the data that is stored in core data from the previous request.  Essentially, it checks whether or not the data in core data is stale based on date stamps.  If it is stale it does a db request.

Comment: The best option is to make sure all updates touch the record in the database. Then you just have to check the the database. This seems the obvious path... Also, you should have mentioned that the sqlite store is online, and Core Data on the device...